# How to know when Speech To Text is finished?

Tags: android, speech-to-text, onactivityresult

I am using speech to text in an Activity where I do others things, too. How could I wait until the speech to text is finished, because I need the text from it.

Now, I get the text onActivityResult and it takes some time until it gets the result and I have other threads working in the same time. I have to make stay one after the other until I get the result onActivityresult. This is how I run Speech to text.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.US);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Hi speak something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        }
```

And this is the onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                        ArrayList<String> result = data
                                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                        message=result.get(0);
                        Log.i("answer", message);

                    }
                    break;
                }


            }



        }
}
```

What I need is to work in the application with the `message` but it take some time until it gets the write text.

Comment: Doesn't the `onActivityResult()` called when the speech activity is finished? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to  use  the value from Speech in the programm, but it takes some time until it updates and I want to wait until it is finished.

Comment: Need to introduce listeners using an eventbus ( https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus ) or simply create an interface which supports callback and register listeners whereever you need the message.

Comment: @Andy  this with eventsbus works even I have more Handlers on the main thread?

Comment: Yes and you can target threads other than ui thread in the event post.

Comment: @Andy Ok , and then how could I change the Handlers?